# How to insert a large xml in a Oracle table CLOB using log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, oracle, log4j, clob

I want to log an xml/text > 3999 chars in a Oracle table CLOB using log4j.xml. Insert query does not work and it says "String too long". I also tried using a procedure, it works fine in Oracle but I donot know how to execute that Procedure from Log4j.xml.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to write your own appender that will call the procedure if the built in jdbc appender doesn't suit your needs. Its fairly easy. See an example here: http://javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2004/jw-1220-toolbox.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mark. I wrote an appender with "INFO level" and      <param name="sql" value="exec TEST_CLOB"/> where TEST_CLOB is my procedure. I am passing values for this proc from java code. I get an error "Invalid SQL". Can you tell what Param name can I declare for a procedure in log4j.xml.

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'I wrote an appender'? It sounds like you've just reused the JDBC appender supplied with Log4j. if you really wrote your own appender (created a class that extends an Appender) you should see how the parameters are supplied. In fact in appenders the parameters get initialized and supplied to appender class by the log4j framework in runtime automatically.